# jQuery code not working in widgets page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add this code to one of my widgets form, but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#select').change(function() {
         $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
     });
     $("#select").change();
 });
</script>

<select class="widefat" id="select">
    <option value="ad1">ad1</option>
    <option value="ad2">ad2</option>
    <option value="ad3">ad3</option>
</select>

<div>
<div id="ad1">ad1</div>
<div id="ad2">ad2</div>
<div id="ad3">ad3</div>
</div>
```

The code should display/hide divs with ids (ad1, ad2, ad3) based on current option selection, but it doesn't do the job on widgets page. Looks like there's something wrong with calling jQuery in the widgets page.

Comment: Please, post the code in the question itself and describe what "not working" means: for example, do you see any error message in the debug log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this probably doesn't work is because Wordpress uses `noConflict()` mode. [From The Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode ( see `wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` ). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.
>
> In the `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for `jQuery` is not available

What you'll need to do is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#select').change(function() {
             $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
        });
        $("#select").change();
    });
</script>
```

This line: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` tells JQuery to use the `$` alias so that you can continue writing JQuery like you're used to seeing.

---

JQuery is not my strong-suit. I was able to get it working though, try this:

```
function form() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('select#select').change( function() {
                    $( '#hide_show div' ).css('display', 'none');
                    $( '#hide_show #' + this.value ).css('display', 'block');
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #hide_show div  {display: none;}
        </style>
         
        <select class="widefat" id="select">
            <option value="ad1">ad1</option>
            <option value="ad2">ad2</option>
            <option value="ad3">ad3</option>
        </select>
         
        <div id="hide_show">
            <div id="ad1">ad1</div>
            <div id="ad2">ad2</div>
            <div id="ad3">ad3</div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Still not working, you can try it yourself: http://pastebin.com/sFWi5XRU

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javascript debug console? [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console). I would also view the source of your page to ensure that JQuery is being included into your page.

Comment: I don't see any errors. Could you please try it yourself? Paste the code in the link above in any theme you have, then go to widgets page and try it.

Comment: I've gotten the function above to work on my installation, you could use that and if you want work your way backwards to find your core mistake, it mostly seemed like jquery quirks to me but maybe there was something vitally wrong.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on default Wordpress installation. It shows up like this: http://i.imgur.com/e4i9ACj.png

Comment: I just copy and pasted my edit into my WordPress which is pretty vanilla and I didn't have a problem with it. You may be cached, [here's the whole pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GD1qtWgV). If that doesn't work you'll need to add antoher pastebin with the modified code.

Comment: This is great! It worked now! I just had to add the container div to the selector for it to work. So instead of `$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();`, it should be `$(".container #" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();`. Thanks so much for your help. You rock!

Comment: I still have a problem with it, the #hide_show div disappears at the start of dropping the widget, and after saving it. Is there a method to call the javascript code at this instances?

Comment: @AhmedSaad You could stick with your original `$("select#select").change();` at the end of your jquery function ( before the closing `(document).ready` ).

Comment: I'm having it already, it doesn't help. Probably I need some ajax code.